# Run ansible playbook only on one of two machines while release in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, ansible

The production environment has 2 VMs. I want to apply cron role to only one of them. What do I do wrong?
(Ansible is running in AzureDevOps while releasing. All VMs are gathered together in one deployment group and ansible playbook is running on both of them)

```
ansible-playbook -i production/inventory provision_cron.yml  -b
```

production/inventory file:

```
[all]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local ansible_user=admin

[cron]
100.100.100.100 ansible_connection=local ansible_user=admin # VM where I want to apply cron role
```

provision_cron.yml file:

```
- hosts: cron
  user: root
  roles:
    - cron
    - analytics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Run ansible playbook only on one of two machines while release in azure devops

From your description , your VMs are in the same Deployment Group.

To run the ansible playbook on one of them, you need to **add tags** for each VMs targets in `Pipelines -> Deployment Group -> Target Deployment Group -> Targets` .

[image]

When you use the Deployment Group in Release Pipeline, you could add tags in **Required tags
field** to filter the target VM .

[image]